# Using cubic-bezier on a transform translate. IE Reverses the animation?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-transitions, microsoft-edge

Below is my test code.

Basically the animation should start off fast and then come to a gradual halt. This works fine in Chrome for both directions, however Internet Explorer (11) seems to reverse the animation when you move the element in the opposite direction.

1. Why is it doing this?
2. Any ideas how I can fix it?

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/qv3syqe1/

```js
$('#move').on('click', function() {
  $('.transform').toggleClass('in out')
});
```

```css
.transform {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.transform.in,
.transform.out {
  transition: transform 5s cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1);
}

.transform.in {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.transform.out {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="transform out">

</div>
<button id="move">
  Move
</button>
```

Comment: I was speaking to the IE team about this previously and they said they'd look into it. I'll poke them again with a link to your question.

Comment: It's ***who*** you know in this business. :)

Comment: Or rather who you chat with in SO chatrooms.

Comment: @Trix Because a version wasn't mentioned, I usually assume latest version. So in this case, 11.

Comment: @BoltClock You've added Edge to my question, does it appear in Edge too? I'm still in the minnows of Windows 7 so can't try it...

Comment: @Trix I understand the point, but It's fairly easy to look at the date a question was posted and work out what the version is/was. Anyone looking at this post in the far future will probably only be looking because they have the same issue anyway. :)

Comment: @Trix Plus, there aren't going to be any more IE's past 11. So if it's not working on 11, it shouldn't work on any others ;)

Answer (score 2):

Setting similars transitions (not reusing it) seems to solve the issue

```js
$('#move').on('click', function() {
  $('.transform').toggleClass('in out')
});
```

```css
.transform {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.transform.in {
  transition: transform 5s cubic-bezier(.18, 1, .22, 1); /* changed .19 to .18 */
}

.transform.out {
  transition: transform 5s cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1);
}

.transform.in {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.transform.out {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="transform out">

</div>
<button id="move">
  Move
</button>
```

Comment: Vals always with the clutch alternatives :)